# Do 3+ ajax calls get 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function where i will call 9 function with each ajax call inside of it. In localhost there is no error, in my web i found this issue.

After the 3rd function is done. The 6 others get a 500 Internal Server Error. So i tried to move the other 6 function to put it inside the function that working (example : getBoardLabelCard(id) have 3 more function-> getStartDate(id),getDueDate(id),getChecklist(id)) and it is working.
Is there any pattern of code in multiple ajax calls or maybe should i do all ajax in one function?

Thank you for any advice you give. Really helps me a lot in the future.

```js
function ajaxModalCard(id)
{
 $("#hiddenCardId").val(id);
 getBoardCard(id);

 getBoardMember(id);

 getBoardLabelCard(id);

 getStartDate(id);

 getDueDate(id);

 getChecklist(id);

 getComment(id);

 getAttachment(id);

 getMoveCard(id);

 $("#changeArchive").show();
 $("#changeSend").hide();
 $("#modal3").openModal();
}

function getBoardCard(id)
{
 var id = id;
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "board/getBoardCard",
    data: {id:id},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response) {
     //alert("response");
     $.each(response, function(idx, response){
        $("#modalCardTitle").text(response.cardTitle);
        $("#modalListTitle").text("in list "+response.listTitle);
        $("#txtCardTitle").val(response.cardTitle);
        $("#hiddenListId").val(response.cardListId);
        $("#textareaDescription").text(response.cardDescription);
        $("#modalCardDescription").text(response.cardDescription);
       });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}

function getMoveCard(id)
{
 var id = id;
 var boardId = $("#hiddenBoardId").val();
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "board/getMoveCard",
    data: {id:id,boardId:boardId},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response) {
     //alert("response");
     $("#selectListCard").empty();
     var gabung = "";
       gabung += "<option value=0 disabled selected>Choose a list</option>";
       $("#selectListCard").append(gabung);
     $.each(response, function(idx, response){
      if(response.listStatus == "1" && response.listArchive == "0")
      {
       var gabung = "";
        gabung += "<option value='"+response.listId+"'>"+response.listTitle+"</option>";
        $("#selectListCard").append(gabung);
      }
       });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });

}

function getBoardMember(id)
{
 var id = id;
 var boardId = $("#hiddenBoardId").val();
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "board/getBoardMember",
    data: {boardId:boardId},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response) {
      $("#assignMembers").empty();
      $("#iconMember").empty();
      $("#iconMember").append("<h6><b>Members</b></h6>");
     $.each(response, function(idx, response){
       if(response.memberStatus == "1") //Artinya terdapat didalam board sbg member, jika di kick atau leave tidak akan ditampilkan
       {
        var checked = getBoardAssignChecked(response.userId);
        var name = getNameUser(response.userId);
        var gabung = "<p>";
        if(checked == "true")
        {
         gabung += "<input type='checkbox' class='assignMembers' id='"+response.userId+"' checked='checked'/>";
         var directory = getDirectoryUser(response.userId);
         var gabung2 = '<img src="'+directory+'" style="border-radius:50%;" width="32px" height="32px" alt="Profile" />';
         $("#iconMember").append(gabung2);
        }
        else
        {
         gabung += "<input type='checkbox' class='assignMembers' id='"+response.userId+"' />";
        }
        gabung += "<label class='black-text' for='"+response.userId+"' />"+name+"</label>";
        gabung +=  "</p>";
        $("#assignMembers").append(gabung);
       }

       });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}

function getBoardAssignChecked(id)
{
 //userId
 var userId = id;
 var cardId = $("#hiddenCardId").val();
 var checked = "false";
 $.ajax({
    async:false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "board/getBoardAssignChecked",
    data: {userId:userId,cardId:cardId},
    success: function (response) {
     checked = response;
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
 return checked;
}

function getBoardLabelCard(id)
{
 var id = id;
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "board/getLabelCard",
    data: {id:id},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response) {
     //alert(response);
      $("#labelred").prop("checked",false);
      $("#labelyellow").prop("checked",false);
      $("#labelgreen").prop("checked",false);
      $("#labelblue").prop("checked",false);
      $("#ajaxLabelCard").empty();
    $("#ajaxLabelCard").append("<h6><b>Label</b></h6>");
     $.each(response, function(idx, response){
       if(response.labelRed == "true")
       {
        $("#labelred").prop("checked",true);
        var label = '<div class="red" style="width:28px;height:28px;border-radius:15%;margin:1px;float:left;"></div>';
        $("#ajaxLabelCard").append(label);
       }
       if(response.labelYellow == "true")
       {
        $("#labelyellow").prop("checked",true);
        var label = '<div class="yellow" style="width:28px;height:28px;border-radius:15%;margin:1px;float:left;"></div>';
        $("#ajaxLabelCard").append(label);
       }
       if(response.labelGreen == "true")
       {
        $("#labelgreen").prop("checked",true);
        var label = '<div class="green" style="width:28px;height:28px;border-radius:15%;margin:1px;float:left;"></div>';
        $("#ajaxLabelCard").append(label);
       }
       if(response.labelBlue == "true")
       {
        $("#labelblue").prop("checked",true);
        var label = '<div class="blue" style="width:28px;height:28px;border-radius:15%;margin:1px;float:left;"></div>';
        $("#ajaxLabelCard").append(label);
       }
       if(response.labelRed == "false" && response.labelYellow == "false" && response.labelGreen == "false" && response.labelBlue == "false")
       {
        $("#ajaxLabelCard").empty();
       }

       });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}

function getStartDate(id)
{
 var id = id;
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "board/getStartDate",
    data: {id:id},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response) {
     $("#ajaxStartDate").empty();
     if(response != "")
     {
     }
     
     $.each(response, function(idx, response){
      //alert(response.startDate); //2018-03-07 12:00:00
      var date = response.startDate;
      var pecah = date.split(" ");
      var tanggal = pecah[0];
      var waktu = pecah[1];
      var tanggal2 = tanggal.split("-");
      var waktu2 = waktu.split(":");
      var tgl = tanggal2[2];
      var bln = tanggal2[1];
      var jam = waktu2[0];
      if(bln == "01")
      {
       bln = "Jan";
      }
      else if(bln == "02")
      {
       bln = "Feb";
      }
      else if(bln == "03")
      {
       bln = "Mar";
      }
      else if(bln == "04")
      {
       bln = "Apr";
      }
      else if(bln == "05")
      {
       bln = "May";
      }
      else if(bln == "06")
      {
       bln = "Jun";
      }
      else if(bln == "07")
      {
       bln = "Jul";
      }
      else if(bln == "08")
      { 
       bln = "Aug";
      }
      else if(bln == "09")
      {
       bln = "Sep";
      }
      else if(bln == "10")
      {
       bln = "Oct";
      }
      else if(bln == "11")
      {
       bln = "Nov";
      }
      else if(bln == "12")
      {
       bln = "Dec";
      }
      if(response.startDateStatus == "1")
      {
       $("#ajaxStartDate").append("<h6><b>Start Date</b></h6>");
       var gabung = "<p>";
       if(response.startDateChecked == "1")
       {
        gabung += "<input type='checkbox' id='sd' onchange='changeStartDateChecked(\""+id+"\")' checked='checked'/>";
       }
       else
       {
        gabung += "<input type='checkbox' id='sd' onchange='changeStartDateChecked(\""+id+"\")' />";
       }
       gabung += "<label for='sd'>"+bln+" "+tgl+" at " +jam+":00 - </label><a class='roleActivityStartDate' style='display:none;' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='deleteStartDate(\""+id+"\")' >Remove</a>";
       gabung += "</p>";
      }

      /*$("#ajaxStartDate").append("<p>");
      $("#ajaxStartDate").append("<input type='checkbox' id='a2' />");
      $("#ajaxStartDate").append("<label for='a2'>"+bln+" "+tgl+" at " +jam+":00</label>");//Feb 26 at 12:00PM*/
      $("#ajaxStartDate").append(gabung);
       });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}

function getDueDate(id)
{
 var id = id;
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "board/getDueDate",
    data: {id:id},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response) {
     $("#ajaxDueDate").empty();
     if(response != "")
     {
     }
     
     $.each(response, function(idx, response){
      //alert(response.startDate); //2018-03-07 12:00:00
      var date = response.dueDate;
      var pecah = date.split(" ");
      var tanggal = pecah[0];
      var waktu = pecah[1];
      var tanggal2 = tanggal.split("-");
      var waktu2 = waktu.split(":");
      var tgl = tanggal2[2];
      var bln = tanggal2[1];
      var jam = waktu2[0];
      if(bln == "01")
      {
       bln = "Jan";
      }
      else if(bln == "02")
      {
       bln = "Feb";
      }
      else if(bln == "03")
      {
       bln = "Mar";
      }
      else if(bln == "04")
      {
       bln = "Apr";
      }
      else if(bln == "05")
      {
       bln = "May";
      }
      else if(bln == "06")
      {
       bln = "Jun";
      }
      else if(bln == "07")
      {
       bln = "Jul";
      }
      else if(bln == "08")
      { 
       bln = "Aug";
      }
      else if(bln == "09")
      {
       bln = "Sept";
      }
      else if(bln == "10")
      {
       bln = "Oct";
      }
      else if(bln == "11")
      {
       bln = "Nov";
      }
      else if(bln == "12")
      {
       bln = "Dec";
      }
      if(response.dueDateStatus == "1")
      {
       $("#ajaxDueDate").append("<h6><b>Due Date</b></h6>");
       var gabung = "<p>";
       if(response.dueDateChecked == "1")
       {
        gabung += "<input type='checkbox' id='dd' onchange='changeDueDateChecked(\""+id+"\")' checked='checked'/>";
       }
       else
       {
        gabung += "<input type='checkbox' id='dd' onchange='changeDueDateChecked(\""+id+"\")' />";
       }
       gabung += "<label for='dd'>"+bln+" "+tgl+" at " +jam+":00 - </label><a class='roleActivityDueDate' style='display:none;' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='deleteDueDate(\""+id+"\")' >Remove</a>";
       gabung += "</p>";
      }
      $("#ajaxDueDate").append(gabung);

       });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}

function getChecklist(id)
{
 var id = id;
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "board/getChecklist",
    data: {id:id},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response) {
     $("#ajaxChecklist").empty();
     $.each(response, function(idx, response){
       if(response.checklistStatus == "1")
       {
        var atas = '<div id="checklist'+response.checklistId+'">';
        var luaratas1 = '<div class="col s12 m6 l10 ">';
        var header = '<h6><b>'+response.checklistTitle+'</b></h6>';
        var progressbar = '<div class="progress"><div id="pb'+response.checklistId+'" class="determinate" style="width:0%"></div></div>';
        //var item ='<p> <input type="checkbox" id="test3" /><label for="test3">Satu</label></p>';
        var item ='<div id="checklistItem'+response.checklistId+'"></div>';
        var addatas ='<div id="item'+response.checklistId+'">';
        var add = '<p><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeInput(\''+response.checklistId+'\')">Add an item</a></p>';
        var addbawah ='</div>';
        var luaratas2 = '</div>';
        var luarbawah1 = '<div class="col s12 m6 l1 roleActivityChecklist" style="display:none;">';
        var tengah = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteChecklist(\''+response.checklistId+'\')">Delete</a>';
        var luarbawah2 = '</div>';
        var a = "</div>";
        var gabung = atas+luaratas1+header+progressbar+item+addatas+add+addbawah+luaratas2+luarbawah1+tengah+luarbawah2+a;
        $("#ajaxChecklist").append(gabung);
        //alert(response.checklistId);
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "board/getChecklistItem",
        data: {id:response.checklistId},
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (response) {
         $.each(response, function(idx, response){
          if(response.itemStatus == "1")
          {

           if(response.itemChecked == "1")
           {
            $("#checklistItem"+response.checklistId).append('<p id="item'+response.itemId+'"> <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="cb'+response.checklistId+'" id="test'+response.itemId+'" onchange="changeItem(\''+response.itemId+'\')" onclick="countPb(\''+response.checklistId+'\')" /><label class="black-text" for="test'+response.itemId+'">'+response.itemTitle+'</label><span style="margin-left:7%;" class="ultra-small"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteChecklistItem(\''+response.itemId+'\')" class="right-align red-text">Delete</a></span></p>');
           }
           else
           {
            $("#checklistItem"+response.checklistId).append('<p id="item'+response.itemId+'"> <input type="checkbox" class="cb'+response.checklistId+'" id="test'+response.itemId+'" onchange="changeItem(\''+response.itemId+'\')" onclick="countPb(\''+response.checklistId+'\')" /><label class="black-text" for="test'+response.itemId+'">'+response.itemTitle+'</label><span style="margin-left:7%;display:none;" class="ultra-small roleActivityChecklist"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteChecklistItem(\''+response.itemId+'\')" class="right-align red-text">Delete</a></span></p>');

           }
           countPb(response.checklistId);
          }
           
          });

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       alert(xhr.status);
       alert(thrownError);
       alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
       }
       
       });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}

function getDirectoryUser(id)
{
 //userId
 var id = id;
 var directory = "";
 $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "board/getDirectoryUser",
    data: {id:id},
    success: function (response) {
     directory = response;

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
 return directory;
}

function getNameUser(id)
{
 var id = id;
 var name = "";
 $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "board/getNameUser",
    data: {id:id},
    success: function (response) {
     name = response;

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
 return name;

}

function getLabelCard(id)
{
 var id = id;
 var label = "";
 $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "board/getLabelCard",
    data: {id:id},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response) {
     label = response;

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
 return label;

}

function getComment(id)
{
 var id = id;
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "board/getComment",
    data: {id:id},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response) {
     //alert(response);
     $("#ajaxComment").empty();
     $.each(response, function(idx, response){
      if(response.commentStatus == "1")
      {
       var directory = getDirectoryUser(response.userId);
       var name = getNameUser(response.userId);
       var gabung = "";
       gabung  += '<div class="row" id="comment'+response.commentId+'">';
     gabung  +=  '<div class="col s12 m4 l1">';
     gabung  +=   '<img src="'+directory+'" style="border-radius:50%;" width="32px" height="32px" alt="Profile" />';
     gabung  +=  '</div>';
     gabung  +=  '<div class="col s12 m4 l11">';
     gabung  +=   '<p style="margin-top:-3px;">';
     gabung  +=    '<b><u>'+name+'</u></b>';
     gabung  +=   '</p>';
     gabung  +=   '<p style="margin-top:-13px;" id="textComment'+response.commentId+'">'+response.commentText+'</p>';
     gabung  +=    '<div id="changeComment'+response.commentId+'" style="margin-top:-25px;margin-bottom:15px;display:none;">';
     gabung  +=      '<textarea id="textareaChangeComment'+response.commentId+'" class="materialize-textarea" >'+response.commentText+'</textarea>';
     gabung +=      '<a class="btn waves-effect waves-light green" style="margin-right:10px;" onclick="changeCommentText(\''+response.commentId+'\')">Change</a>';
     gabung +=      '<a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light" onclick="closeEditComment(\''+response.commentId+'\')"><i class="mdi-content-clear"></i></a>';
     gabung  +=     '</div>';
     gabung  +=   '<p class="ultra-small grey-text darken-4" style="margin-top:-10px;">';
     gabung  +=    'yesterday at 8:17 PM - <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeReply(\''+response.commentId+'\')"><u>Reply</u></a> - <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="editComment(\''+response.commentId+'\')"><u>Edit</u></a> - <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="deleteComment(\''+response.commentId+'\')"><u>Delete</u></a>' ;
     gabung  +=   '</p>';
     gabung +=   '<div id="ajaxReplyComment'+response.commentId+'">';
     gabung  +=     '<div class="col s12 m6 l12" id="changeReply'+response.commentId+'">';
     gabung  +=     '</div>';
     gabung  +=   '</div>';
     gabung  +=  '</div>';
     gabung  += '</div>';
     $("#ajaxComment").append(gabung);
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "board/getReplyComment",
       data: {commentId:response.commentId},
       dataType:"json",
       success: function (response) {
        //alert(response);
        $("#ajaxReplyComment"+response.commentId).empty();
        $.each(response, function(idx, response){
         if(response.replyStatus == "1")
         {
          var name2 = getNameUser(response.userId);
          var directory2 = getDirectoryUser(response.userId);
          var gabung2 = "";
          gabung2  += '<div id="replyUser'+response.replyId+'">';
        gabung2  += '<div class="col s12 m4 l1">';
        gabung2  +=  '<img src="'+directory+'" style="border-radius:50%;" width="32px" height="32px" alt="Profile" />';
        gabung2  += '</div>';
        gabung2  += '<div class="col s12 m4 l11">';
        gabung2  +=  '<p style="margin-top:-3px;">';
        gabung2  +=   '<b><u>'+name+'</u></b>';
        gabung2  +=  '</p>';
        gabung2  +=  '<p id="textReply'+response.replyId+'" style="margin-top:-13px;">'+response.replyText+'</p>';
        gabung2  +=    '<div id="changeReply'+response.replyId+'" style="margin-top:-25px;margin-bottom:15px;display:none;">';
        gabung2  +=      '<textarea id="textareaChangeReply'+response.replyId+'" class="materialize-textarea" >'+response.replyText+'</textarea>';
        gabung2  +=      '<a class="btn waves-effect waves-light green" style="margin-right:10px;" onclick="changeReplyText(\''+response.replyId+'\')">Change</a>';
        gabung2  +=      '<a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light" onclick="closeEditReply(\''+response.replyId+'\')"><i class="mdi-content-clear"></i></a>';
        gabung2  +=     '</div>';
        gabung2  +=  '<p class="ultra-small grey-text darken-4" style="margin-top:-10px;">';
        gabung2  +=   'yesterday at 8:17 PM - <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="editReply(\''+response.replyId+'\')"><u>Edit</u></a> - <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteReply(\''+response.replyId+'\')"><u>Delete</u></a>' ;
        gabung2  +=  '</p>';
        gabung2  += '</div>';
        gabung2  += '</div>';
        $("#ajaxReplyComment"+response.commentId).append(gabung2);
         }
          });
       },
       error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
      alert(xhr.responseText);
       }
     });
      }
     
       });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
   alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `should i do all ajax in one function?` Yes, making a single AJAX request to return all this information would be a *far* better idea. You're effectively flooding your server with requests from a single source at the moment.

Comment: ohh okay thanks for the answer. think i have some bad experience with this. will learn about this mistakes!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but is flooding server with request okay? :D

Comment: No, not at all. This is why I mentioned to make a single request which returns all the data.